# hierarchical paging address mask

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, paging, bitmask

I came across the following c code which is intended to run on a **32-bit machine** and produce bit masks for the page-directory-addresses and page-table-addresses in 2-hierarchical-paging:

```
#define PAGE_DIRECTORY_ADDRESS_MASK (~((uint64_t)0xfff))
#define PAGE_TABLE_ADDRESS_MASK (~((uint32_t)0xfff))
```

Wouldn't both return the same result?

```
   20 bits       12 bits
+--------------+--------+
| 1...........1|0......0|
+--------------+--------+
32           12 11     0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question! They may seem to be the same but:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#define PAGE_DIRECTORY_ADDRESS_MASK (~((uint64_t)0xfff))
#define PAGE_TABLE_ADDRESS_MASK (~((uint32_t)0xfff))

int main()
{  
    uint64_t a = PAGE_DIRECTORY_ADDRESS_MASK;
    uint64_t b = PAGE_TABLE_ADDRESS_MASK;

    if (PAGE_DIRECTORY_ADDRESS_MASK != PAGE_TABLE_ADDRESS_MASK)
        printf("Different: %llx %llx\n",PAGE_DIRECTORY_ADDRESS_MASK, PAGE_TABLE_ADDRESS_MASK);

    if (a != b)
        printf("Different! %llx %llx\n",a, b);

    return 0;        
}
```

Output:

```
Different: fffffffffffff000 fffff000                                                                                                         
Different! fffffffffffff000 fffff000
```

Comment: You're using the wrong format modifier for `uint64_t`. There's no guarantee that `uint64_t` is the same as `unsigned long`, it might be `unsigned long long`. Use the standard [format macro constants](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer#Format_macro_constants) instead.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you for your comment! Good point! I have adjusted the code to use `"%llx"`  `"ll"` length modifier was added to `Standard C` in `C99`.